# Limiting Periodicity of Sequences with $\aleph_0$ Subsequential Limits.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Given a bounded real sequence $(x_n)_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, let us denote the set of subsequential limits as $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ \vert\ \exists(x_{n_k})_{k}\to x\}$. We can also define the limiting period of a bounded sequence as $T[(x_n)_n]:=\inf\{t\in\mathbb{N}:(x_{n}-x_{n+t})_{n}\to0\}$. With this in mind, I was wondering about the relationship between $T[(x_n)_n]$ and the cardinality of $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$. My question then is

$$\bbox[#CCCCFF,2pt,border: 2px solid blue]{\text{Is it true that }|\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]|=\aleph_0\Rightarrow T[(x_n)_n]=+\infty?}$$

On one side, I have been able to prove that, if $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$ is finite, then $T[(x_n)_n]\geq|\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]|$ which seems to indicate that, extrapolating, the answer to the previous question will be affirmative. On the other side, the sequence $(x_n)_n $ defined as
$$(x_n)_n:=\left(0,1,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{1}{4},0,\dots\right)$$
is bounded and $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]=[0,1]$ since $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$ is closed and $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\subseteq\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$ is dense in $[0,1]$. But
$$(x_{n}-x_{n+1})_n=\left(-1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},...\right)\to0$$
which means that it is a sequence with $2^{\aleph_0}$ subsequential limits and limiting period $1$. This may be indicating that the answer to the said question could be, in fact, negative.

---

$\color{red}{\textbf{Update:}}$ I've already managed to solve it but, if you find an alternate proof, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prove a more general result that will yield to the desired answer, in this case affirmative. For a given set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, I'll be denoting $\text{iso}(S):=\{x\in S\ \vert\ \exists\epsilon>0:(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap S=\{x\}\}$ the set of isolated points of $S$.

$\color{#7200FF}{\textbf{Lemma 1.}}$ *Let $(x_n)_{n}$ be a real bounded non-convergent sequence with $x\in\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])$. Then, there exists $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ (with $I$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus I$ infinite) such that $(x_n)_{n\in I}\to x$ and $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus I}]=\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n}]\setminus\{x\}$.*

*Proof.* Since $x$ is an isolated sequential limit, we know that $\exists \epsilon>0:(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]=\{x\}$. With this in mind, define $I:=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|x_n-x|<\epsilon/2\}$ and let's try to prove that this index set does indeed satisfy the desired conditions. Clearly $I$ is infinite as, if this wasn't the case, we would have that $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\geq n_0:|x_n-x|\geq\epsilon/2$ which would imply that $x\not\in\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$. Also, $\mathbb{N}\setminus I$ must also be infinite as, if this wasn't the case, we would have that $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\geq n_0:|x_n-x|<\epsilon/2$ which would imply that $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]=\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\cap (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)=\{x\}$ while $(x_n)_n$ isn't convergent. To prove that $(x_n)_{n\in I}\to x$, notice that $x\in\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\Rightarrow \exists (x_{n_k})_{k}\to x$ and
$$\exists k_0\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall k\geq k_0:|x_{n_k}-x|<\epsilon/2\Rightarrow (x_{n_k})_{k\geq k_0}\subseteq (x_n)_{n\in I}\Rightarrow x\in\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in I}]$$
where we have $\{x\}\subseteq\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in I}]\subseteq\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\cap (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)=\{x\}\Rightarrow (x_n)_{n\in I}\to x$. Lastly, to prove that $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus I}]=\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\setminus\{x\}$ notice that $x'\in\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\setminus\{x\}\Rightarrow\exists (x_{n'_k})_{k}\to x'$ where $\{n'_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cap\{n_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ must be finite so that $\exists k_0\in\mathbb{N}:\{n'_k:k\geq k_0\}\cap\{n_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}=\emptyset$ and, hence, $(x_{n'_k})_{k\geq k_0}\subseteq (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus I}\Rightarrow x'\in\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus I}]$. Thereby, we also have $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus I}]=\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n}]\setminus\{x\}$ as $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n}]\setminus\{x\}\subseteq\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus I}]\subseteq\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\setminus (x-\epsilon/2,x+\epsilon/2)=\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\setminus\{x\}$. $\square$

$\color{#7200FF}{\textbf{Lemma 2.}}$ *Let $(x_n)_{n}$ be a real bounded non-convergent sequence and let $\{x^1,...,x^m\}\subsetneq\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])$* be a propper finite subset of isolated points. Then, $T[(x_n)_n]>m$.

*Proof.* Applying Lemma 1 $m$ times, we get that we can find disjoint $\{I_1,...,I_m\}$ in such a way that, denoting $I_0:=\mathbb{N}\setminus\left(I_1\cup...\cup I_m\right)$, $\forall 1\leq k\leq m:(x_n)_{n\in I_k}\to x^k$ and $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in {I_0}}]=\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\setminus\{x^1,...,x^m\}$. If $T[(x_n)_n]=+\infty$, the inequality would be trivial. So, from now on, let's assume that $T[(x_n)_n]=:t\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, since $\lim_n(x_n-x_{n+t})=0$, it follows that, for $k\in\{1,...,m\}$, $(x_n)_{n\in t+I_k}\to x^k$ as well. Now, if $k'\in\{0,...,m\}$ is such that $(t+I_k)\cap I_{k'}$ is infinite, it will also happen that $x^{k'}\in\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_{n\in I_k}]$. But this can only be the case if $k=k'$ so $k'\neq k\Rightarrow(t+I_k)\cap I_{k'}$ finite and, hence,
$$\exists n_k\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\geq n_k:n\in t+I_k\Rightarrow n\in I_k$$
so, by taking $n'_k\in I_k\Rightarrow n'_k+t\in t+I_k$ such that $n'_k+t\geq n_k$, we have that $n'_k+t\mathbb{N}\subseteq I_k$. Thereby, every set of the family $\{I_k:1\leq k\leq m\}$ contains an infinite arithmetic sequence with common difference $t$. And, as there are only $t$ residues mod $t$ (i.e. there are only $t$ different arithmetic sequences of naturals with common difference $t$) it follows that $t>m$. $\square$

$\color{#7200FF}{\textbf{Lemma 3.}}$ *For every $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the set of isolated points $\text{iso}(S)$ is countable.*

*Proof.* Note that every point of $\text{iso}(S)$ is an isolated point of $\text{iso}(S)$ itself. Thus, the induced subspace $(\text{iso}(S),\mathcal{T}_u\vert_{\text{iso}(S)})=(\text{iso}(S),\mathcal{T}_D)$ has discrete topology. And, since $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_u)$ is second countable, $(\text{iso}(S),\mathcal{T}_D)$ must also be second countable as it is a subspace of a second countable space. But, with the discrete topology, this can only happen if $\text{iso}(S)$ itself is countable. $\square$

$\color{#9B00FF}{\textbf{Proposition.}}$ *Let $(x_n)_{n}$ be a real bounded sequence. Then $T[(x_n)_n]\geq|\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])|$ (where we make use of the abuse of notation $+\infty:=\inf\emptyset\geq\aleph_0$).*

*Proof.* If $\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])$ was finite, we can conclude from Lemma 2 that $T[(x_n)_n]>|\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])|-1$ or, equivalently, that $T[(x_n)_n]\geq|\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])|$. Otherwise, if $\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])$ was infinite, we know by Lemma 3 that $|\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])|=\aleph_0$ so we can write $\{x^k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}=\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])$. Now, by applying Lemma 2 on every $\{x^1,...,x^m\}\subsetneq\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]),m\in\mathbb{N}$, we conclude that $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}:T[(x_n)_n]>m$ so that $T[(x_n)_n]=+\infty\geq\aleph_0=|\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])|$ necessarily. $\square$

$\color{#7200FF}{\textbf{Corollary.}}$ *Let $(x_n)_n$ be a real bounded sequence with $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$ countable. Then, $T[(x_n)_n]\geq |\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]|$*.

*Proof.* If $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$ is finite, then $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]=\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])$ so the previous proposition applies. If $|\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]|=\aleph_0$, then $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$ is a closed countable set and, since every perfect set (closed set with no isolated points) [is uncountable](https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/topo/proofs/pfctuncb.html), there must be an isolated point $x^1\in\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$. Recursively, if $\{x^1,...,x^m\}\subseteq\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]$ where isolated points, $\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]\setminus\{x^1,...,x^m\}$ will also be a countable closed set. This means that $\exists\{x^m:m\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])$ and, consequently, $|\text{iso}(\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n])|=\aleph_0=|\mathfrak{S}[(x_n)_n]|$ which ends the proof by the previous proposition. $\square$